# proliferation of dynamic_reconfigure servers due to image_proc or image_transport

Tags: ros, dynamic-reconfigure, image-proc, image-transport, stere-image-proc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi-

I've noticed recently that it has become increasingly difficult to make use of the dynamic reconfigure gui because there are too many servers in the dropdown list. It seems now every image transport is adding two servers to the list, one for "compressed" and one for "theora".

When the PR2 is running there is more than a whole screen's worth of dynamic reconfigure servers just for the image processing stuff. Trying to find or quickly switch between servers in the drop down menu is really annoying... I've resorted to making my servers of interest start with 'a_' so that I can find them first, but this seems hacky/unsustainable.

Is there any way to set a flag that tells some of those image transport nodes that I don't want them to advertise their servers? Or to tell the gui to ignore a set of nodes? (Maybe the servers could advertise a priority, like the different ROS_INFO/ROS_WARN levels, or they could belong to groups that are easier to manage.)

Ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11236/proliferation-of-dynamic_reconfigure-servers-due-to-image_proc-or-image_transport/) by [aleeper](https://answers.ros.org/users/35/aleeper/) on ROS Answers with karma: 573 on 2011-09-16

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could write a Trac enhancement ticket for `dynamic_reconfigure` for this. Maybe something along the lines of Eric's suggestion. We are currently planning Fuerte changes, maybe this could be included.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-09-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Seems to me that a good solution would be to make the dropdown list a tree structure based on namespace. This would be analogous to, say, how Nautilus displays a folder hierarchy in "List" view, replacing folders with namespaces and files with actual dynamic_reconfigure servers.

I think this would keep the number of nodes available to select manageable as long as your ROS nodes are namespaced well.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-09-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2